# What is the app binary? (iTunes Connect error)

Tags: ios, binaryfiles

I'm getting an error "Invalid product identifier" when I enter my class with IAP's... I figure it may be because iTunes Connect says I need to upload my binary first... but what's a binary? Is it just the project? I'm not ready to fully release the app though.

Comment: Is this just during testing?  You do not need to upload your app to test IAP. You should check that the product identifier you had in your code matches the product identifier you have in iTunesConnect and that the app bundle Id matches the app in iTunesConnect

Comment: product id is not associated with bundle identifier correctly while testing iAP , check once

Comment: Bundle Identifier under target is the exact same as it is on Connect. Product identifiers are also identical to what is on Connect.